# What is the meaning of the locus of points P satisfying some conditions?

Tags: definition, conic-sections

> A rod AB of length 15 cm rests in between two coordinate axes in such a way that the end point A lies on x axis and end point B lies on y axis. A point P(x,y) is taken on the rod in such a way that AP = 6 cm. Show that the locus of P is an ellipse.

I understand the definitions of the rod and of P. But I can't make heads or tails of the last statement. What is meant by the locus of P?

Comment: Unfortunately the above question would not fit in the title section.

Comment: The coordinates (x,y) of P satisfy a certain equation. Find this equation. Show that this equation describes an ellipse in the plane (x,y).

Comment: If your rod has endpoints $A=(x_0,0)$ and $B=(0,y_0)$ then you know that $x_0^2+y_0^2=15^2$. The point $P$ is the point which is $6$ away from $A$ and $9$ away from $B$. The "locus" is the set of all $P$ as $x_0,y_0$ vary.

Comment: Has it occurred to you that entering "locus" into a search engine might bring something useful?

Comment: @Sally Unfortunately, only a few minutes after the first answer was posted. I guess you get kind of slow after going through 50+ boring problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locus of P is the set of points which P covers/forms, when A and B are being moved/varied while still satisfying the conditions from the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

As A and B move along the x and y axes, respectively, P moves over the xy-plane.